# Regex in makefile

Tags: regex, makefile

I am trying to find how to use regular expressions in a makefile, for example:

```
foo:
ifeq ($(bar),^ver[0-9]+)
     do something
else ($(baz),word)
     do something else
endif
```

When i type,

`foo bar = ver1.1.0` - must do "do something",

`foo baz = word` - must do "do something else".

This doesn't work. Can someone help me to understand how to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make can't handle regular expressions, so it must delegate that work to the shell:

```
ZAP := $(shell [[ $(bar) =~ ver[0-9.]+$$ ]] && echo matched)

foo:
ifdef ZAP
    @echo BLUE
else
    @echo GREEN
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this doesn't  work, because you are use BASH syntax, must be DASH (Makefile use DASH for default interpreter ). And syntax is not correct.

Comment: I've never heard of DASH before. Can it handle regex matching? Do you have access to any tool that can?

Comment: You can read about DASH in wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell. I found solution, just use patter. Thanks!